# Are there any predecessors to the leveling concept of Kierkegaard?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind, history-of-philosophy

What were the most likely sources of inspiration of Kierkegaard in creating the leveling concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I have not read any Kierkegaard in many many years, I believe that he was inspired by the importance of Kantian notions of individual moral agents/agency, and, especially,  by his great aversion to Hegel and his "leveling" notions of the collective, absolute, objective mind;  desiring instead to emphasize the importance of the individual [and his/her] mind.

As he posited, "truth is subjectivity,” i.e. "An objective uncertainty held fast in an appropriation-process of the most passionate inwardness is the truth, the highest truth attainable for the individual."  Though, as i said,  I have not read any Kierkegaard in a very long time, I believe this is from his *Concluding Unscientific Postscript to Philosophical Fragments*.  Have a look here https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kierkegaard/.